# How to make buttons appear behind a background, or make the buttons background transparent?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

(Note: The buttons with borders are part of the background)
[image]
I would like to place the real buttons behind the image so it would like i'm pressing the button in the background, however, i'm actually pressing the button behind it.

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller

    background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="Mainmenu.png")  # Displays whats in the file
    background_label = tk.Label(self, image=background_image)  # Makes tk.Label display the background_image
    background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)  # Adjusts the height/width

    background_label.image = background_image  # Recognises the label as an image

    button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Play", bg="red", fg="black", height=2, width=15,
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Play"))
    button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Settings", bg="yellow", fg="black", height=2, width=15,
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Settings"))
    button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", bg="white", fg="black", height=2, width=15, cursor="pirate",
                        command=exit)

    button1.place(x="300",y="240")
    button2.place(x="480",y="240")
    button3.place(x="390",y="300")
    button1.config(font=("System", 10))
    button2.config(font=("System", 10))
    button3.config(font=("System", 10))
```

Comment: You cannot do what you are asking in your title. However you can add the image to the button itself and then provide the text to go over it.

Comment: Why do you want buttons at all? Why not let the user click directly on the background?

Comment: How would this be done Bryan Oakley?

Comment: You can bind `"<Button-1>"` to a function that executes different commands depending on the mouse location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: let the user click directly on the background

1. Define a class object inherited from `tk.Canvas`

   ```
   class Menu(tk.Canvas):
       def __init__(self, parent, image, command, show_areas=False):
           """
           Init a Canvas object, displaying a image
           Bind the Mouse click to a function
           Init a dict to hold the added clickable areas

           :param parent: The parent widget
           :param image: The image object
           :param command: The callback command to handle area clicks
           :param show_areas: For debug/trace purpose. If 'True'show the clickable areas.
           """
           super().__init__(parent)
           # Feed TKinter the image
           self._image = image
           self.create_image(0, 0, image=self._image, anchor='nw')

           self.callback = command
           self.bind('<Button-1>', self.Button_1_func)

           self.show_areas = show_areas
           self.areas = {}
   ```
2. The Mouse-Click-Handler function.
   Search for a matching area and call the `.callback` function with the `tag`

   ```
       def Button_1_func(self, event):
           for tag, (x, y, x2, y2) in self.areas.items():
               if event.x in range(x, x2) and event.y in range(y, y2):
                   event.tag = tag
                   self.callback(event)
                   return 'break'
   ```
3. Add a new clickable area with given `tag` and computed geometry.
   `15 * 10` computes the area `width`
   `5 * 10` computes the area `height`
   If `self.show_areas` is `True`, create a rectangle with the geometry.

   ```
       def add_area(self, tag, coord):
           self.areas[tag] = *coord, (coord[0] + (15 * 10)) + 1, (coord[1] + (5 * 10)) + 1

           if self.show_areas:
               self.create_rectangle(self.areas[tag])
   ```

> **Usage**:

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Displays as background_image what's in the file
        self.menu = Menu(self,
                         image=tk.PhotoImage(file="Mainmenu.png"),
                         command=self.command,
                         show_areas=True)
        self.menu.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        for tag, coords in [('Play', (300, 240)), 
                            ('Settings', (480, 240)), 
                            ('Quit', (390, 300))]:
            self.menu.add_area(tag, coords)

    def show_frame(self, key):
        # Simulating controller.show_frame
        print('show_frame({})'.format(key))

    def command(self, event):
        if event.tag in ['Play', 'Settings']:
            self.show_frame(event.tag)

        if event.tag == 'Quit':
            self.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***