# How to Create Clickable Locations on a Single Image Using Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

Hello I am new to using Tkinter for creating GUIs. What I am trying to do is create a window that is just an image, and I would like to user to be able to click on different items that are present in the image. Based on the item clicked, certain code will execute.

An ideal solution would be to place invisible buttons on top of the image in specified locations. My buttons need to be pixel perfect so I tried creating frames and having the buttons fill those frames. However, it doesn't seem I can make the buttons or the frames transparent.

Comment: You want a Canvas and rectangles (to which you can bind mouse events), rather than frames and buttons.

Comment: Why not just bind to the canvas without overlaying anything, and then use the coordinate from the event to determine which function to run?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [let the user click directly on the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55936650/how-to-make-buttons-appear-behind-a-background-or-make-the-buttons-background-t)